# Cant apply Distinct on List of matrices mathdotnet C# mathdotnet

Tags: c#, matrix, math.net

I have a List of Matrix (Math.net.Numerics)on which I want to find if all are different. I did List.Distinct().Count(). But in a particular case the List has only 1 3x5 matrix and Applying Distinct on the same fetches me an error. I see that the same error exist if the matrix has 2 rows. But 1 row or more than 3 doesn't make any error.

Update:

Error : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: So the error has no error-message and you don't have code to show?

Comment: Is `Matrix` a reference type or a value type?